# How to connect to local sdf file?

Tags: c#, sql, database-connection, sqlcedatareader

I'm creating a simple windows C# form application. but I cannot connect to local database file (.sdf)

i'm using

```
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
```

**This is my app.config file**

```
<add name="ConnectionString1"
       connectionString="Data Source=D:\Work Place_VS\Dilshan_Hardware\Dilshan_Hardware\Database\AppDB.sdf"
       providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />

 <add name="ConnectionString2"
       connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database\AppDB.sdf"
       providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />
```

**I am trying to connect database file through following code.**

```
try
   {
      using (SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString1"].ToString()))
   {
     SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT routeName FROM tbl_route", cn);
     cn.Open();
     SqlCeDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader1.Read())
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Result :" + reader1[0]);
     }
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("Error :" + ex.ToString());

}
```

Even I use `ConnectionString1` or `ConnectionString2` it always jump into catch block while try to make connectionString.

Please help me to find the error of this code.

Comment: what is the Exception Message?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a `Persist Security` Info value

Try the following:

```
<add name="ConnectionString1"
           connectionString="Data Source=D:\Work Place_VS\Dilshan_Hardware\Dilshan_Hardware\Database\AppDB.sdf;Persist Security Info=false;"
           providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5"
```